ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.packages.six.moves' in a simple weather app
When I run the code, I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.packages.six.moves", this is despite the fact that I have uninstalled and reinstalled six, requests and urllib3 many times.
Code:
import requests
import json


def get_weather(city, api_key):
    base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"


    complete_url = base_url + "q=" + city + "&appid=" + api_key + "&units=metric"

    response = requests.get(complete_url)
    data = response.json()

    if data["cod"] != "404":
        main = data["main"]
        wind = data["wind"]
        weather = data["weather"][0]
        temperature = main["temp"]
        humidity = main["humidity"]
        weather_description = weather["description"]
        wind_speed = wind["speed"]

        print(f"City: {city}")
        print(f"Temperature: {temperature}°C")
        print(f"Humidity: {humidity}%")
        print(f"Weather: {weather_description.capitalize()}")
        print(f"Wind Speed: {wind_speed} m/s")

    else:
        print(f"City {city} not found. Please enter a valid city name.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    api_key = "5a249ac961fe0222f884ded14818c13e"
    city = input("Enter city name: ")
    get_weather(city, api_key)

I tried to run the program, a text output was meant to appear which then asked for the users city for them to then input it and weather info to appear. I have tried reinstalling six, requests and urllib3, deleted a 0kb version of python in the microsoft directory and done "sfc /scannow".

for an inquiry, this works fine in Ubuntu! I assume you're running this code in Windows, right? Did you try pip install requests --upgrade
pip install urllib3 --upgrade ?

Could you please share full error trace of your error

There is not enough information here. What is the os, which version of python is installed and which versions of the relevant packages?

Your code also works fine in Windows. Are you using a virtual environment? If not,  try "pip list" at a command prompt to verify that urllib3 is in the list. If you are using a virtual environment, activate it and do a "pip list" at a command prompt and check the list for urllib3. It's possible that the environment (virtual or system) you are using when you run the code still doesn't have urllib3 installed.
